# Flex Mobile label underline single word

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.6

The spark label in Flex Mobile doesn't supprt the htmlText, so how can I e.g. underline a single word in a Flex Mobile spark label??

Answer (score 0):

```
        <s:Label
        textDecoration.hovered="underline"
```